# How can I prove that this matrix is positive definite?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

I want to prove, that the matrix
$
\Gamma:=\Big(\min\{t_i,t_j\}-t_i\cdot t_j\Big)_{1\leq i,j\leq k}\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}
$
is positive definite where $0\leq t_1<\ldots<t_k\leq 1$.

I tried several things, but nothing worked. Thanks for help!

Edit: I already know, that $\Gamma$ is positive semi-definite, because it is the covariance function of the brownian bridge.
So it would be enough to show, that 0 is'nt an eigenvalue of $\Gamma$, which has a lot of equvivalences, like $\text{rg}\,\Gamma=k$ for example. But even this I cannot proof.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: 1) Using the definition I tried to check $\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^k x_i\cdot x_j\cdot(\min\{t_i,t_j\}-t_i\cdot t_j)\\$.

2) I've tried to calculate the determinant of the matrix (if the determinants of all upper-left submatrices are positive, that would be enough).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this claim is correct. For instance, consider $\{t_{1}, t_{2} \} = \{1/2, 1 \}$ Then. 
$\Gamma = \left( \begin{matrix} 1/4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$. Then $\Gamma$ has eigenvalues $0,1/4$, which implies that $\Gamma$ is not positive definite because $0$ is an eigenvalue of $\Gamma$ with eigenvector $\langle 0 , 1 \rangle$. 
 
I think if $0 < t_{1} \leq \dots \leq t_{k} < 1$ then the claim might be true. In this case, you just have to show that $det(\Gamma) > 0$, and then you can use induction to claim that the upper left sub-matrices have positive determinant (induct on the dimension). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes but it's true for $0<t_i<1$

Comment: Thank you for this correction of the bounds!

But I already tried to calculate $\det\Gamma$, but I failed. In similar situations, l always suceed with laplace expansion, but in this case, I don't have any idea:
$\det\Gamma=
 \begin{vmatrix}
   t_1-t_1^2 & t_1-t_1\cdot t_2 & \ldots & t_1-t_1\cdot t_k\\
   t_1-t_1\cdot t_2 & t_2-t_2^2 & \ldots & t_2-t_2\cdot t_k\\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
   t_1-t_1\cdot t_k & t_2-t_2\cdot t_k & \ldots & t_k-t_k^2
  \end{vmatrix}\\
$

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be
$
\det(\Gamma)=t_1\cdot(1-t_k)\cdot\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}(t_{i+1}-t_i)
$
but I have no idea how to proove this :/
Shure, induction over $k$ prooves this, but I don't know how I the indecution step looks like. Any ideas?